# What is a guard block for a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, ide, header, header-files, codeblocks

I'm trying to make a C++ class using the Code::Blocks IDE and there is a field called "Guard block." I've done a search and haven't been able to find any useful information. What is this field for? Thanks.

Comment: [Include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) possibly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Guard blocks are used to protect against the inclusion of a header file multiple times by the same compilation unit (c++ file). They look something like this:

```
// Foo.h
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILE_NAME_HERE_H_
#define INCLUDE_FILE_NAME_HERE_H_

class Foo
{
};


#endif
```

If you include the same file multiple files, you will end up with multiple definition error. Using of include guards isn't necessary in small projects but becomes critical in any medium to large sized projects. I use it routinely on any header files I write.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. One more thing is that I see the header file of the class I've created being included in the class .cpp file itself, which doesn't really make sense to me. I'm not sure why Code::Blocks is doing this =/

Comment: @Quicksort the header is included in the .cpp because the types and constants are defined in the header and classes are declared there.

Comment: Thanks David. Good god you are quick with the replies. So the header file of my class ("Deck.cpp") simply provides the compiler with a list of all the declarations that possibly could occur in the main.cpp without including any implementation details so there is no compile error and, if the item is indeed instantiated in the main file, the compiler then looks for the Deck.cpp file associated with the header file and inserts the implementation details into main.cpp?

Comment: @Quicksort Hmm. It's not quite like that but it's pretty hard to go into the gory details in a comments. Mainly header files are useful in that they allow you to call functions in other translation units without having to write out the declarations more than once. They key here is to understand the difference between declaration and definition.

Comment: OK. I'll do some more searching. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Guard blocks are used to prevent a header file being included multiple times in a single translation unit. This is often a problem when you include a number of header files that in turn include common standard header files.

The problem with multiple inclusions of the same file is that it results in the same symbol being defined multiple times.

Guard clauses can be handled with `#define` and `#ifdef` statements but are much simpler with the non-standard, but universal, `#pragma once`.

```
// foo.h
#pragma once

int foo(void);
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is the use of "#pragma once" something that is common in industry?

Comment: It depends. If you are paranoid about portability then you won't use it because it is not portable, i.e. supported by the standard. But all popular compilers implement it and so in practice that's not an issue. If you do one day happen upon one that doesn't then it's easy enough to switch to old-style guards.

Comment: `#IFNDEF MYTHING \n #DEFINE MYTHING \n #pragma once` is fast on all compilers where it's possible to be fast (make sure ifdef is first)

Comment: @MooingDuck why have the #ifndef .... if you use #pragma once? Is that to gain portability?

Comment: @MooingDuck will compilers that don't support `#pragma once` error if you do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, SethCarnegie: Some compilers detect that a header begins with `#IFNDEF` and will not even _touch_ the file the second time if it begins with that.  A compiler that understands `#pragma once` will also do that, but pragma doesn't have to be the first thing in the file.  A compiler that doesn't understand a `#pragma` is required by the C standard to ignore it.  A stupid compiler will open the file, and be blocked by the `#IFNDEF` (the second time).