# Why do i get a typedef error while compiling TSS file with original headers?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, include, typedef

I have a problem compiling a tss file. Somehow there seems to be a conflict in a type definition, although i include the headers of an official function "Tss2_Sys_GetRandom.c".

```
In file included from botan_rng.cpp:9:
/home/pi/TPM_Scripts/Scripts/tpm2-tss/src/tss2-sys/sysapi_util.h:67:8: error: using typedef-name ‘TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT’ after ‘struct’
 struct TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/TPM_Scripts/Scripts/tpm2-tss/src/tss2-sys/sysapi_util.h:12,
                 from botan_rng.cpp:9:
/home/pi/TPM_Scripts/Scripts/tpm2-tss/include/tss2/tss2_sys.h:26:46: note: ‘TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT’ has a previous declaration here
 typedef struct _TSS2_SYS_OPAQUE_CONTEXT_BLOB TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT;
```

The includes look like this:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2
  3 #ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
  4 #include <config.h>
  5 #endif
  6
  7 #include "tss2_tpm2_types.h"
  8 #include "tss2_mu.h"
  9 #include "sysapi_util.h"
 10
 11 #include <botan/botan.h>
 12
 13 using namespace std;
 14 using namespace Botan;
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is happenning? The TSS includes are the same as they are in "Tss2_Sys_GetRandom.c", and the GetRandom Function works properly, if i call it in terminal, so why is there a conflict, when i try to compile the exact same include paths.

Tss2_Sys_GetRandom.c looks like this:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-2-Clause */
/***********************************************************************;
 * Copyright (c) 2015 - 2017, Intel Corporation
 * All rights reserved.
 ***********************************************************************/

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include "tss2_tpm2_types.h"
#include "tss2_mu.h"
#include "sysapi_util.h"
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: _has a previous declaration here
 typedef struct _TSS2_SYS_OPAQUE_CONTEXT_BLOB TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT;_   Do you need [header guard blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841788/what-is-a-guard-block-for-a-header-file-in-c)

Comment: You tried to declare two different things with the same name. Don't do that.

Comment: `src/tss2-sys/sysapi_util.h` This doesn't sound like a file that you are supposed to include. Anyway, assuming that's the same file as [on github](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/src/tss2-sys/sysapi_util.h) there is no `struct TSS2_SYS_CONTEXT;` declared or defined in it, so you'll need to provide more context and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).